# Add lang-js syntax highlighting hint for google-apps-script

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Posts with the `google-apps-script` tag currently do not have syntax highlighting applied. When I manually set a code block's language with `<!-- language: lang-js -->`, the syntax highlighting works as expected.

As I understand things, the implication is that the tag currently has a null syntax highlighting hint.

I propose that the `google-apps-script` tag have its highlighting hint set to lang-js.